# importance of implication vs its tautology

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I'm self-taught in logic, started with programming. Texts stress the importance of the implication operator but I fail to see operator's importance. It was always intuitively clear that,

$$ p \rightarrow q \equiv \neg \ p \lor q $$

Keeping that in mind, my questions are:

- Does implication allow for additional rewrite rules or higher understanding in some form?
- Is sequent form, with its heavy use of implication rules, more "powerful" than nth-order logic with propositional syntax? Are there additional, or significantly simpler rewrite rules for some class of statements?
- The operator itself is counterintuitive, YMMV. Having the statement true in case the first operand is not, doesn't seem right or necessary at all. What am I missing?

I hope the question itself isn't too vague. I've hit these roadblocks in understanding of logic and haven't found answers in a long time.

Comment: With regard to your third question, if I understand what you're asking, consider the following. It is always true that $\neg p \lor p$. Now, since if $p$ is true, then $q$ is true, we can rewrite the first assertion as $\neg p \lor q$.

Comment: For your third point, I would submit that what is counterintuitive is not how the $\to$ connective works; it is simply pragmatic that we often need a connective with that truth table, especially for putting below a universal quantifier, and $\to$ is a perfectly good mnemonic symbol for that; $p\to q$ is "the thing that converts knowledge of $p$ (if/when we acquire that knowledge) to knowledge of $q$". What you find counterintuitive is _explaining_ that particular truth table as "If $p$ then $q$".

Comment: I'm puzzled by what you mean by "sequent form, with its heavy use of implication rules" -- on the contrary, using sequent calculus as your proof system _downplays_ the importance of the $\to$ connective considerably relative to Hilbert systems (where you can't do _anything_ without a truckload of implications) or even natural deduction.

Comment: @HenningMakholm the confusing parts are 1) "what if not p" and 2) from your intuitive explanation "why knowledge of q is needless if p is false". It's as if there's some philosophical meaning behind the operator that I'm missing.

Comment: @sthalik: But isn't it the "if $p$ then $q$" explanation that leads you to think those are problems in the first place? If we had written it $p\mathrel{\circ\!\!-\!\!\!\!\times}q$ instead and never claimed that it would have anything to do with the word "if", "then" or "implies", would you then have any philosophical objection to considering a connective with that particular truth table?

Comment: @HenningMakholm reasoning about sequent forms, from my vague experience, seems as use of formally named reasoning (i.e. several terms in Latin). OTOH reasoning close to software logic, whether infix or parenthesized Polish notation, is something so pliable as barely needing intermediate steps to hold in memory, YMMV. Could you provide an ISBN, DOI or otherwise for a terse guide on sequent calculus, please?

Comment: @sthalik: [Sequent calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequent_calculus).

Comment: @HenningMakholm agreed. Is there an intuitive term to describe "implies" truth table? It's even calling it "implies" that's counterintuitive here.

Comment: @HenningMakholm please post an answer so that I can select your explanation in the comments as the answer. And thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a surprisingly interesting question. I think part of the reason for the confusion is that propositional logic is a kind of two-headed beast:

- On one hand, it is a system for calculating with the truth values "yes" and "no", digital logic and so forth. In this use it is also the prototypical example of a *Boolean algebra* (which ought to be a familiar word for someone coming from software).
- On another hand, propositional logic is commonly taught in mathematical-logic texts for the sole purpose of being a *didactic stepping stone* towards proof system for *predicate logic*, which is what mathematical logicians are interested in for the purpose of formalizing proofs in mainstream mathematics.

It so happens that in the *first* of these usages of propositional logic, you hardly ever see a $\to$. For these purposes, $\land$ and $\lor$ and $\neg$ (as well as, in some cases, XOR, NAND, NOR ...) serve us quite fine.

Where you do see $\to$ is in logic texts that are written with the ulterior motive of introducing quantifiers later on. This is because $\to$ is basically designed to be useful *together with a quantifier*: We can express, for example

> All dogs are mammals

symbolically as
$$ \forall x(\mathit{dog}(x) \to \mathit{mammal}(x)) $$

In this particular context the $\to$ makes better sense; together with $\forall$ it is part of a team that expresses that *if* we're looking at a dog, *then* implicitly we're also looking at a mammal.

It is technically convenient to split the "all A are B" into one part -- the $\forall$ -- that is about making universal claims *in general* and one part -- the $\to$ -- that helps formulating this *particular* kind of universal claim.

Once we have $\forall x$ that will allow us to express claims about *more than one thing* (perhaps an infinity of things) at once, what we need in order to get all the way to "all dogs are mammals" is to express: No matter what you're looking at, it will be either a dog and a mammal, or a non-dog mammal, or something that is neither a dog nor a mammal. If and only if it is true for *everything* in the world that it falls into one of those three classes, then it is true in general that all dogs are mammals.

The truth table for $\to$ is then what collects this potential-property-of-everything into a single uniform claim for each $x$ that we can apply our $\forall$ to.

The *downside* of this split is only that it makes it irresistable for textbook authors to present a flood of rules and exercises for this nice new connective *before* they introduce the $\forall$ -- but before we have $\forall$ there is no really good motivation for how $\to$ behaves in the first place, and attempts to explain it generally ends up as linguistic smoke and mirrors at best, or blantant arguments from authority at worst.

In summary: Once you put the $\to$ below a $\forall$ it makes perfect sense. If you *don't* have a relevant $\forall$ around the $\to$, the meaning often ends up counterintuitive and can only be understood simply by having accepted that this is the truth table we want.

Consider for example the [drinker paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drinker_paradox):

$$ \exists x( p(x)\to\forall x(p(x)) $$

which is logically valid according to both the proof rules and the official semantics of predicate logic, but fails to make a lot of intuitive sense because the $\to$ has been written under an $\exists$ instead of under a $\forall$.

---

For completeness I should mention that there are some after-the-fact applications of propositional logic that fall into neither of the two broad categories above. One prominent example of this is the [Curry-Howard correspondence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry%E2%80%93Howard_correspondence) between proof systems for propositional calculus (in particular for *intuitionistic logic*) and **type systems** for functional programming languages. Here the $\to$ connective achieves fundamental importance -- even though quantifiers are rarely around -- it is what turns out to correspond to *function types* on the type-system side of things.

Comment: Thank you for the elucidating "forall" PROLOG-like formula, as well as the discussion under the original question.

Answer (score 1):

The operator does seem counterintuitive, but it correctly captures what we mean by "if" in many cases. For example, "If we're out of milk, then I'll go to the store" isn't saying that I won't go to the store anyway if we have plenty of milk - we might be out of eggs. For a more mathematical example, "if $p$ is a prime greater than $2$, then $p$ is not even" is not making any claims about the parity of non-primes. It's certainly true that there are many cases in which we *don't* want this interpretation; "if I say 'run', run!" seems to mean that you shouldn't run if I don't tell you to. But the formalism of propositional logic doesn't allow us to change the interpretation of a connective by context, so we had to choose one. The one that was chosen, by convention, is the first interpretation.

As for why we use it: it's certainly true that it isn't necessary. Then again, $\vee$ isn't necessary either; by DeMorgan's laws we can make do with $\wedge$ and $\neg$. But additional symbols like $\vee$ and $\to$ vastly improve clarity (the meaning of $p \vee q$, for example, is much easier to understand than $\neg(\neg p \wedge \neg q)$). They also allow us to use new inference rules or equivalences - the rules governing $\vee$ and $\to$ are consequences of the rules for $\wedge$ and $\neg$, but it's much easier to use (for example) modus ponens rather than a huge chain of rules about negations and disjunctions.

So, to reiterate: $\to$ is not at all necessary, but it improves clarity and makes proofs much more convenient.

Answer (score 0):

It is interesting that you say that it is 'intuitively clear' to you that:

$p \rightarrow q \equiv \neg p \lor q$

but you also say that 'having the statement true when the first operand is not doesn't seem right'

since $\neg p \lor q$ is true whenever $p$ is not.

Anyway, here are some further equivalence rules for the conditional:

$\neg (p \rightarrow q) \equiv p \land \neg q$ (Negation Implication)

$p \rightarrow q \equiv \neg q \rightarrow \neg p$ (Contraposition)

$p \rightarrow (q \rightarrow r) \equiv (p \land q) \rightarrow r$ (Exportation)

$p \rightarrow (q \land r) \equiv (p \rightarrow q) \land (p \rightarrow r)$ (left Distribution $\rightarrow$ over $\land$)

$(p \lor q) \rightarrow r \equiv (p \rightarrow r) \land (q \rightarrow r)$ (right 'distribution' ... But not really since the $\lor$ becomes a $\land$)

Comment: Thank you for the rewrite rules. The confusing part was the vernacular usage of the "implication" term, say -- wanting to find out something that's not proper to ask by asking another question, where the improper question's answer follows from the proper question's answer. Or -- showing one's guilt by knowledge of particular details is "implying it" in vernacular. I will study the operator due to its perceived importance at least.